# How to solve "words-cut" when there's spaces?

Tags: html, css

I've been working in a tooltip library. The idea is simple: Add in any HTML element the *custom data attribute* (I mean `data-`) with the message that the user wants to show in the tooltip, for example:

```
<div data-msg="Message">Hover me.</div>
```

When the user hover the mouse on the element, the tooltip has show it.

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leoMestizo/P3aRL/7/)**.

If you see in the above example, you'll see that when the user adds a message with spaces  the browser cut the words in the spaces, but when the user adds a message without spaces, the browser don't cut the words (because there is no spaces).

I've been trying to fix the problem with `white-space`, `break-word` and `text-overflow`, but they don't resolve it.

**This is very important:** I don't want to put a specific `width`, for leave that the browser calculates the element's width automatically. I could fix this problem adding a specific `width` but I don't want that.

If anyone know how fix this problem, I'd like to explain me the behavior of this issue.

Thanks,
Leo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it works by adding

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in `[data-msg]::before {}`

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QHD3A/

Comment: You rock! I tried the `white-space` property but with these values: *pre-wrap* and *pre-line*. *nowrap* value not ocurred to me. I thought that this property together with `word-wrap: break-word` would have weird behaviors. Thank you very much!